# how to export selected item into Excel asp mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

i want to export selected item into excel and i exported this item into excel but the problem is my header filed is repeated  my export action method code is here

```
      public ActionResult ExportExcel(int[] cid)
       {

        var grid = new GridView();
        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=candidateRecord.xls");
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
        var candidate = IcandidateRepository.Candidate.ToList();
        foreach (var candidateid in cid)
        {
            grid.DataSource = from p in candidate where(p.CandidateID==candidateid) select new { name = p.FirstName, companyName = p.Company.CompanyName };


            grid.DataBind();
            grid.RenderControl(hw);
        }
        Response.Write(sw);
        Response.End();![enter image description here][1]
        return view();
```

}

my excel sheet data is here  please any one help me how to remove this duplication header field

```
    name    companyName
    sandeep Lear Automotive India
    name    companyName
    sanjay  ïƒ˜ JSW Steel Limited
    name    companyName
    dabar   Lear Automotive India
    name    companyName
    manoj   jcob
    name    companyName
    kumar   sdf
    name    companyName
    shoaib  Accenture
```

Comment: You shouldn't be using `Response.Whatever()` in that way in ASP.NET MVC. [Go do some nice ASP.NET MVC tutorials](http://www.asp.net/mvc)! :)

Comment: i got solution using linq query

Answer (score 0):

this code is working fine

```
  public ActionResult ExportExcel(int[] cid )
    {

        var grid = new GridView();
        Response.ClearContent();

        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=candidateRecord.xls");
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
        var candidate = IcandidateRepository.Candidate.ToList();

            grid.DataSource = from p in candidate where cid.Contains(p.CandidateID) select new { name = p.FirstName, companyName = p.Company.CompanyName };


            grid.DataBind();
            grid.RenderControl(hw);

       Response.Write(sw);
        Response.End();
        return View();
    }
```